# cmake error: no version information available

Tags: linux, cmake, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to run cmake on a Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian Jessie, following [this](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi) guide.
After installing `cmake` by running `sudo apt-get install cmake`, I get the following error when typing `cmake` at the command line:

```
cmake: cmake: no version information available (required by cmake)
```

this is repeated a dozen times or so, and concluded by:

```
cmake: relocation error: cmake: symbol, version GLIBC_2.4 not defined in file with link time reference
```

I checked that I have only 1 version of cmake installed: `which cmake` returns `/usr/bin/cmake`, and the `/usr/bin` folder only has 1 `cmake` file in it. Running `/usr/bin/cmake` explicitly results in the same errors with `cmake` replaced by `/usr/bin/cmake`. Could anyone advise on what might be going on and how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Please expand your question to a step-by-step list what you did and indicate in which step the problem occured.

Comment: I've linked the guide I'm using, but the problem essentially starts right after running sudo apt-get isntall cmake. I've actually just managed to fix it too, I'll post the answer in a minute.

Comment: As the problem is unrelated to CMake, you might consider closing it.

Comment: I believe others who might run into the same problem with the same error message may find this helpful. If you think this violates forum rules, I can close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm that the problem cannot be replicated on a different SD card. I conclude that the error was possibly due to corrupted data on a bad SD card. From what I've seen, here are some things to look for that might indicate a bad SD card:

- Automatic resize by raspi-config does not result in the root
  filesystem being expanded as seen by raspberry pi (df -h shows a
  smaller rootfs size than the card size).
- The filesystem is by default mounted as read-only. As a consequence X
  Window manager doesn't start, and startx fails to invoke it.
- Various errors when running sudo-apt-get upgrade that can't be fixed
  by rerunning sudo apt-get update.

Finally, I would suggest steering clear of generic SD cards, the one that didn't work for me was one of that variety.